# Bootstrap Glyphicons not vertically aligning on bottom Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have used the social buttons on my website which are displayed on the navbar at the bottom of my page but for some reason they are not vertically centered. Here is a snippet of my code for the footer/navbar i would like the icons to be vertically centered.

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
 <div class="container">
   <button class="btn btn-twitter pull-right"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
   <button class="btn btn-google-plus pull-right"><i class="fa fa-google-plus</i>
   <button class="btn btn-facebook pull-right"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
 </div>
 </div>
```

This is what it is currently turning out like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nvmg.jpg

Comment: what if you try `vertical-align: middle` for each button?

Comment: Nope doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `.navbar-button` class.

Something like:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</nav>`

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons